# Error en condición de Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo el siguiente problema

```
private void Formato(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvMineria.Rows)
    {

        if (r.Cells["Estado"].Value.ToString() == "Pendiente")
        {
            dgvMineria.Columns["realizarPase"].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Quiero hacer una condición que si todo lo que traiga el datagridview en la columna estado sea igual a pendiente que me oculte el botón realizar pase de lo contrario que me lo muestre

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @BigCode podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
int totalFilas = dgvMineria.Rows.Count;

var filasPendientes = (from DataGridViewRow r in dgMineria
where r.Cells["Estado"].Value.ToString() == "Pendiente" 
select r).Count();

if(totalFilas == filasPendientes)
{
   dgMineria.Columns["realizarPase"].Visible = false;
}
```

Para lograr esto primero obtenemos el total de filas del **DataGrid** y posteriormente haciendo uso de **Linq** obtendríamos el total de filas cuyas celdas correspondientes a la **columna Estado** tienen como valor **"Pendiente"**. Posteriormente comparamos las **variables totalFilas** y **totalPendientes**, y de ser iguales entonces hacemos invisible a la **columna realizarPase**.

**Nota:** Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```